# How to pick random items through cumulative probability?

Tags: c#, math, random, probability

### Exercise Background

The exercise consists in generating a 2D map with a user given x,y size of said map, and then place on each cell of the map random items from a table.
I have a cell in an [x, y] coordinate of an Items matrix and I have to pick items randomly for every cell of this matrix.

### My Problem

I have to select random items from a table of 4 items that have their probabilities shown in cumulative probability, and a cell that has such items can have more than 1 and different combinations of those items.

I don't really know how to go about this problem, taking in account that 2 of the items have the same probability on the given table for the homework.

This is the table of probability given:

```
Food - 1
Weapons - 0.5
Enemy - 0.5
Trap - 0.3
```

My Items enumeration:

```
[Flags]
enum Items
{
    Food = 1<<0,
    Weapon = 1<<1,
    Enemy = 1<<2,
    Trap = 1<<3
}
```

Again, the expected output is to pick randomly through this percentages what items does 1 cell have. What I'd like to have as an answer would be just a start or a way to go about this problem please, I still want to try and do it myself, avoid complete code solutions if you can.

Comment: Pick a random number between 0 and 2.3 and then use cumulative probability : Food - 1
Weapons - 1.5
Enemy - 2.0
Trap - 2.3  So Weapon would be between 1 and 1.5

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by 'a cell that has such items can have more than 1 and different combinations of those items.'?

Comment: @Megadardery what i mean by that is each element of the matrix I explained can have more than one Item randomly picked inside it, so you can have the combination Food+Enemy, or Weapon + trap for example.

Comment: If that's the case, then these are not cumulative probabilities for picking alternatives, they're probably individual probabilities of picking each item.  In other words, every cell should have food, half the cells should have a weapon, half the cells should have an enemy, and 30% of the cells should have a trap, on average.  If that's so, then the answer you accepted would be wrong because it only picks one item per cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to work with integers in this type of problem, so I'll work with:

```
Food - 10
Weapons - 5
Enemy - 5
Trap - 3
```

That gives a total of 10 + 5 + 5 + 3 = 23 total possible options.

Most computer RNGs work from base 0, so split the 23 options (as in 0..22) like this:

```
Food - 0..9 giving 10 options.
Weapons - 10..14 giving 5 options.
Enemy - 15..19 giving 5 options.
Trap - 20..22 giving 3 options.
```

Work through the possibilities in order, stopping when you reach the selected option.  I will use pseudocode as my C++ is very rusty:

```
function pickFWET()

  pick <- randomInRange(0 to 22);

  if (pick < 10) return FOOD;
  if (pick < 15) return WEAPONS;      
  if (pick < 20) return ENEMY;
  if (pick < 23) return TRAP;

  // If we reach here then there was an error.
  throwError("Wrong pick in pickFWET");

end function pickFWET
```

Answer (score 0):

If two items have the same cumulative probability then the probability of getting the latter item is 0. Double check the probability table, but if it is correct, then 'Weapons' is not a valid option to get.

However in general. If you could 'somehow' generate a random number between 0 and 1, the problem would be easy right? With a few if conditions you can choose one of the options given this random number.

With a little bit of search you can easily find how to generate a random number in whatever language you desire.

Comment: yes, generating the number is easy. The table looks wrong to me at first glance but i thought it was something that was missing that I wasn't remembering, because if weapons and enemies have the same probability one of them is infact impossible if the table is in cumulative probabilities